# InfoPath 2010 and SharePoint 2013 Claims Based

Tags: infopath, claims-based-auth, claims, service-account

I cant get InfoPath 2010 to auto populate current user in SharePoint 2013, It keeps populating service account. I know this has to do with claims based auth but I can't see any reasonably workaround on the internet. Any suggestions?